# Linux: Is it possible to encrypt a file so everybody in our organisation can view it? (but no one else) -> s/mime

Tags: encryption, certificates

In my organisation we have all s/mime installed in our email clients so we can verify our ID and send encrypted mails. These personal certificates are backed by a trusted server certificate. This system is in place and works fine.

Is it possible to uses these tools, to encrypt a file only meant for the eyes of the co-workers? The application/method should be command line based and apart from the email client.

ty

Comment: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html Share the private key.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov That's not good security practice. Encrypting a decryption key for mutiple recipiants with their respective public key is a better solution.

Comment: That means you'll have to distribute not one but the same file multiple times which could be quite an intricate issue unless it's automated using a backend/web server.

Comment: @Artem not necessarily, files can be encrypted in such a way that any one of multiple keys can decrypt them (by encrypting the session key multiple times, as Danny said).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov See [RFC 5652](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652) for ways to encrypt a file for multiple recipients, which is probably how the email system in question encrypts emails.  In short, **one** random AES key is generated, used to encrypt the data, and then that 16-byte (for AES-256) key (the "envelope key") is then encrypted using the public key from the X509 certificates of **each** of the users meant to be able to decrypt the data. For 2048-byte RSA keys, the encrypted AES key will be 256 bytes.  Each of those encrypted keys is attached to the data,

Comment: (cont) And anyone with access to the private key corresponding to one of the public keys used to encrypt the envelope key can then use that private key to decrypt the encrypted envelope key and then use the recovered AES key to decrypt the data.